# How to enable flash only for FIreFox

Tags: 12.10, firefox, flash

I have two browser on my Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. Chromium and FireFox.
I want to install flash player but only for FireFox to play game and music. But not for Chromium.
Can someone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have successfully installed Flash and that it works for Firefox, you can simply prevent Chromium from using Flash. To do so, type `about:plugins` in the Chromium browser's address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then look at the list of plug-ins enabled, and just disable anything related to Flash.

Such a step will only affect Chromium and not Firefox.

Note that Firefox has a click-to-play option for plug-ins as well. If you wish to enable that feature, type `about:config` in the Firefox address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Answer `okay` in the resulting screen and then, in the next screen, type `click` and look for a line with `plugins.click_to_play`. Go to that line and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will toggle the click-to-play feature on or off.

---

I don't use 64-bit myself and have heard that getting Flash to work *may be* problematic, but, in any case, make sure you have allowed ubuntu-restricted-extras and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```